# AWS Elasticsearch performance issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6.5

Have an index which is search heavy. Rpm varies from 15-20k. Issue is, for first few days resp time of search query will be around 15ms. But it will start increasing gradually and touches ~70ms. Some of the requests starts queuing(as per Search thread pool graph in aws console) but there were no rejection. Queuing would increase latency of the search request.

Got to know that queuing will happen if there is pressure on resource. I think I have sufficient cpu and memory, plz look at config below.
Enabled slow query logs, but didnt find any anamoly. Even though average resp time is around 16ms, I see few queries going above 50ms. But there was no issue in search query. Searchable documents is around 8k.

Need your suggestion on how to improve performance here. Document mapping, search query and ES config are given below. Is there any issue in mapping or query here?

Mapping:

```
{
  "data":{
    "mappings":{
      "_doc":{
        "properties":{
          "a":{
            "type":"keyword"
          },
          "b":{
            "type":"keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search query:

```
{
  "size":5000,
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "filter":[
        {
          "terms":{
            "a":[
              "all",
              "abc"
            ],
            "boost":1
          }
        },
        {
          "terms":{
            "b":[
              "all",
              123
            ],
            "boost":1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative":true,
      "boost":1
    }
  },
  "stored_fields":[]
}
```

Im using keyword in mapping and terms in search query as I want to search for exact value.Boost and adjust_pure_negative are added automatically. From what I read, they should not affect performance.

Index settings:

```
{
  "data":{
    "settings":{
      "index":{
        "number_of_shards":"1",
        "provided_name":"data",
        "creation_date":"12345678154072",
        "number_of_replicas":"7", 
        "uuid":"3asd233Q9KkE-2ndu344",
        "version":{
          "created":"10499"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ES config:

- Master node instance type: m5.large.search
- Master nodes: 3
- Data node instance type: m5.2xlarge.search
- Data nodes: 8 (8 vcpu, 32 GB memory)